# How to isolate a void print() method for testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I wrote a long division application, which I now want to test. 
Simplifying it a bit, I have: [Classes simplified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Gh2.png)

1. InputData class containing two longs: dividend and divisor. InputData instance is supplied to Division.
2. After creating an instance division, I run divide() method on it to produce OutputData.
3. OutputData contains all info about each stage of the division process and metadata of the result (integer or not, periodic or not, etc.)
4. Finally OutputData is an input to printer.print(), which I want to test.

[printer output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk1qE.png)

The question is how to properly use mocks\stubs\spies to test the void print method of printer class? My teacher says I cannot have any variables except outputData and OutputStream to test the printer and suggested to read about mockito.

Let's say I want to test the correctness of printer output with those inputs: -943 and 225. My non-isolated version looks like this:

```
@Test
void testPrintDivisionNegativePositiveRecurrentExpansion() {
    final long VALID_INPUT_DIVIDEND = -943;
    final long VALID_INPUT_DIVISOR = 225;
    inputData = new InputData(VALID_INPUT_DIVIDEND, VALID_INPUT_DIVISOR);
    Division division = new Division(inputData);
    OutputData outputData = division.divide();
    printer.print(outputData, streamOut);
    String actual = streamOut.toString();
    String expected = "_-943|225\r\n" + " -900|--------\r\n" + " ----|-4.19(1)\r\n" + " _-430\r\n" + "  -225\r\n"
            + "  ----\r\n" + " _-2050\r\n" + "  -2025\r\n" + "  -----\r\n" + "   _-250\r\n" + "    -225\r\n"
            + "    ----\r\n" + "     -25\r\n";
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

I read about mocking and stubbing, but most of the examples suggest using when().then() and return simple string or int, whereas in my case outputData will contain List each with 5 fields. [outputData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUkrH.png)

I somewhat see how I can use spy() for this, but if I understand correctly spy() runs the actual method, so the dependency is still there and complete isolation will not be achived. Then why is my version of test worse?

Comment: You don't need Mockito, InputData, Division, to test a method of Printer taking an OutputData and an OutputStream as argument. All you need is a Printer, an OutputData, and an OutputStream. Creating the Printer and the OutputData should be trivial. Regarding the stream, the simplest way is to use a ByteArrayOutputStream, call the method, transform the stream to a byte array, and see if it contains the expected bytes.

Comment: yes, that is how I do it with streamOut, it is a ByteArrayOutputStream. But how do I create OutputData? It should look like this http://prntscr.com/ijh959

Comment: `new OutputData(the, required, arguments)`? I.e. the same way you're creating it inside the Division.divide() method.

Comment: the required arguments are not trivial as can be seen here https://prnt.sc/ijh959 and they are computed inside divide(). should I do the computation on paper and then manually create allStages variable? But even then it will be dependent on the class Stage().

Comment: You can use the Division class to create an OutputData if it makes things simpler for your test. The core point is that Mockito is irrelevant. Call your print method with a ByteArrayOutputStream as argument, and check that the expected bytes have been written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What is you code under test?

This is the most important question you have to answer.

Any other class having its own business logic your code interacts with should be mocked.

From your tests name I guess that the `printer` object is your code under test and `OutputData` is a dependency providing (for your test case) unrelated business logic. Therefore you should mock that:

```
class MyTestClass {
  @Rule public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule(); 
  @Mock OutputData outputData;
  @Test
  void testPrintDivisionNegativePositiveRecurrentExpansion() {
    // configure mock of OutputData
    printer.print(outputData, streamOut);
    String actual = streamOut.toString();
    String expected = "_-943|225\r\n" + " -900|--------\r\n" + " ----|-4.19(1)\r\n" + " _-430\r\n" + "  -225\r\n"
        + "  ----\r\n" + " _-2050\r\n" + "  -2025\r\n" + "  -----\r\n" + "   _-250\r\n" + "    -225\r\n"
        + "    ----\r\n" + "     -25\r\n";
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }
}
```

> I read about mocking and stubbing, but most of the examples suggest using when().then() and return simple string or int, whereas in my case outputData will contain List each with 5 fields.

There is no big difference in mocking when your return type is complex or a `List`. You create an instance of it and configure your mock to return that:

```
class MyTestClass {
  @Rule public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule(); 
  @Mock OutputData outputData;
  @Test
  void testPrintDivisionNegativePositiveRecurrentExpansion() {
    List<YourElementType> inputData= Arrays.asList(new YourElementType(dummyValues1), new YourElementType(dummyValues2), new YourElementType(dummyValues3)); 
    doReturn(inputData).when(outputData).getValuesToPrint();
    printer.print(outputData, streamOut);
    // ...
```

Comment: Take a look at my example outputData please https://prnt.sc/ijh959
If I get it right, I should assign these values by hand right? But even then outputData will be a List<Stage> thus using the class Stage.

Comment: @Andrey *"I should assign these values by hand right?"* Yes. **--** *"But even then `outputData` will be a `List<Stage>` thus using the class Stage."* Yes.